# OpenCart | Как восстановить данные из БД?

Tags: opencart

Здравствуйте!
У меня был сайт на OpenCart, случайно вычистил FTP перепутав соединения, БД осталась целой, как восстановить сайт?

Я где-то слышал что картинки пропадут, большого значения не имеет, главное чтобы сайт ожил.

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: И бэкапов никаких нет?

Answer (score 0):

Первым делом смотрите на хосте бекапы. Нормальные хосты по-тихому бекапят вас по дефолту, моло ли что. Если нет, то заливайте чистый opencart заново на хост, в файлах `admin/config.php` и `корень_сайта/config.php` правте:

```
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli(или какой экстеншн вы используете, но 99.99% это он)');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'ваш_mysql_server');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'ваше_имя_пользователя_бд');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'ваш_пароль_на_бд');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'drgold_drmshop');
define('DB_PORT', '3306(стандартно, но если заругается - го к хостеру)');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'префик_таблиц_вашей_дб');
```

Важный момент - вспоминайте, какие сторонние расширения/модули использовали и устанавливайте их все на новый магазин. Иначе бд будет засорена и могут быть проблемы с кешем и ваще.